# http post submission error with orbeon forms

Tags: xforms, orbeon

im using orbeon's xforms engine in separate war mode. The XForms is displayed correctly, but when i'm trying to send a http post, it throws an error.
My submit tag:

< xforms:submission id="save-submission" ref="instance('books-instance')" action="http://localhost:8080/myproject/hello" method="post" replace="none" />

My servlet, which should deal with the POST, is on the /hello url in my app.
I tried the action attribute with "/myproject/hello", "/hello", etc, but none of them works.

I captured the http post with wireshark, and the message is:
POST /myproject/orbeon/xforms-server

How can I send the HTTP POST directly to my servlet? 
Why does it want to send the request to /orbeon?  Where's the mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two POSTs you should be able to see with WireShark:

1. One from browser to the server, done to `/myproject/orbeon/xforms-server` (Ajax).
2. The submission done from Orbeon Forms to `http://localhost:8080/myproject/hello`.

If you don't see #2, it might be because the instance is invalid, or some other reason. To figure this out, I'd recommend you use [development-level logging](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-logging#TOC-Development-configuration) and check the `orbeon.log` for more information on what is happening at the time the submission runs.

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful feature! My servlet generated NUllPointerException... Now it works fine!